# Get exact output of SQLite string

Tags: python, sqlite

In my Python program, I'm trying to print a string (or TEXT to be exact) from an SQLite database, but it gets printed with a lot of formatting.

For example, this

```
SELECT street FROM stores WHERE id = 202
```

prints

```
[{'street': 'Wall Street'}]
```

However, I would like it to just print

`Wall Street`

**How do I achieve that?**

I've tried `TRIM`, `printf`, `fetchone` and `fetchall` with varying formatting results, but none completely stripped of SQL-added formatting.

Comment: It is not SQL-added formatting. The data returned is a Python data structure (a `list` of `dict`s in the example above) and what you _print_ is the string representation of that data structure. You should extract the value you need from that structure. For the example in the question, for example, it would be `response[0]["street"]`.

Comment: Thank you Selcuk. Would you mind showing what the syntax would be to achieve that?

Comment: this is not formatting my friend. This is the data structure you are getting back. It is a list of dicts. In your case it has only one item. You could start  with result[0] which would peel the list off. Then I dont know if you want to have key and value or just value, but both are pretty straight forward.

Comment: @thestacker I'm sorry, what do you mean by the syntax? Is the example I included in my comment sufficient? If not, we can help more if you post the actual code.

Comment: `response[0]["street"]` was already said. I think no one can add to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have successfully retrieved an object that looks like this: `[{'street': 'Wall Street'}]` You currently have a list that contains a single dictionary.

As a quick example of handling such objects, try this:

```
test = [{'street': 'Wall Street'}]
for data in test:
   print(data["street"])

# prints "Wall Street"
```

This will loop through "all" (one, in this case) of the entries in the list, and on each entry of the list it will target the dictionary key "street", printing the corresponding value, which in this case is "Wall Street".

Happy coding!